# Multiple python nested for loops, possibly recursively traverse lists. python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, riot-games-api

I am trying to match the first item in participantId to the first list in str(each['participantId']). And then the second item in participantId to second list, and so on.

```
participantId = ['2','5','7','4','10','9','2']

each['participantId'] = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                         [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

So I want to use a for loop on participantId but have just the first item in the list do an if statement with the first list, then the second item in participantId do an if statement with the second list. As of Now my code just matches all participantId's with each list. here is a snippet of my code:

```
for each in json['participants']:
                for x in str(each['participantId']):
                    print(x)
                    for i in participantId:
                       if x == i:
                            kills = each['stats']['deaths']
                            print('kills')
                            print(kills)
```

I have looked at recursively traverse lists as a solution but I cant seem to make that work. I'm very new to python and coding so maybe there is some function im missing.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, the final operation `each['stats']['deaths']` has no dependency on the `participantId` you are currently looking at. The `for x ...` and `for i ...` loops have absolutely no effect on `each`??

Comment: The stats dont need to be influenced by the for loops. I just want to call those stats on the condition that the first participantId matches with the list. So on the condition that those are met they print the kills. Perhaps if i include more of the code it will make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using dictionary comprehension for something like this.
For example:

```
participant_data = {
        _id: data for _id, data in \
        zip(participantId, each['participantId'])
        }
```

will make `participant_data` a dictionary where the keys are the items in `participantId`, and the values are the items in `each['participantId']`. To get the data for a specific id, you just need to use `participant_data[id_of_participant]`.